# What can you do with quantified uncertainty in latent variable time-series models?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bayesian, uncertainty, state-space-models

Uncertainty quantification in latent variable models is a topic I am interested in, but I am struggling to grasp the difference between what you can do with quantified parameter uncertainty and quantified uncertainty in the latent state. This is particularly ambiguous to me in applications involving time-series models (such as SSMs).

Given a sequential latent model with posterior belief $p(z_t|x_{1:T}; \theta)$ and transition probability $p(z_t|z_{t-1}; \phi)$, our goal is to estimate these distributions (e.g. using variational inference) to be able to both extract the underlying causal explanations for observed data and make predictions about the future.

I understand that estimating these distributions give us the uncertainty in the latent state (e.g. the variance in the posterior), and that by using Bayesian methods to find $p(\theta|z, x)$ we can quantify uncertainty in the fitted parameters, but what do these quantities actually help us do regarding making predictions about future timesteps, and what's the difference between what we can do with each of them?

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/303705) that might help.

Comment: Are you interested in predicting a new observation, $x_{t+1}$?  You could do so by estimating $p(x_{t+1} | x_{1:T}, \theta)$ -- which is a function of the estimated densities that you listed.

Comment: @RachelAltman I'm more interested in predicting latent states. For more context, the motivation comes from learning latent dynamics models of partially observable MDPs in model-based reinforcement learning. At a high level the goal would be to use quantified uncertainty in the latent state to guide decision making (e.g. conservative actions for high uncertainty states), but whether uncertainty in $z$ or uncertainty in $\theta$ is needed for that is confusing me.

Comment: I haven't studied that particular problem. Maybe [this paper](http://mistis.inrialpes.fr/people/jbdurand/Publis/compstat2014_guedon.pdf) and the references therein will give you some ideas.